# Flurry and IAP conflict

Tags: in-app-purchase, conflict, flurry

We found that ios could not monitor iap(iOS) during the flurry process using version 6.3.0. we search libflurry.a library and found the flurry sdk called function "addtransactionobserver" to intercept iap。
How to solve this problem?

Comment: iap=In-App Purchase, Flurry sdk for unity

Comment: The latest version of the Flurry plugin is v3.1.0. The latest SDK version is 11.x.x. What is version 6.3.0 referring to?

Comment: flurry-sdk-2.7.0.unitypackage

Answer (score 0):

I set SetIAPReportingEnabled (false) is also invalid